# Parse Java reflection class

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say I have a method called `Object classInstance = createInstance("Page", map, factory)` which creates an instance of "Page" with java reflection and does some stuff with it. For demonstration purposes I've called it "Page", but it could be any of my classes.

Now I want to add this object to a `List<Page>`. To call `list.add(classInstance)` and add it to the list I need to parse it to "Page". Is there a way to do it, given the only information I have is the string containing the class name? So instead of doing `(Page) classInstance` I need to do something like `(Class.forName("Page")) classInstance`.

I can not modify the List or the way it is added to the list.

Thank you.

Edit: here is the createInstance Method:

```
    private static Object createInstance(String className, Map<?, ?> map, Meilenstein2Factory factory) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

    try {
        String createMethodName = "create" + className;
        Method createMethod = factory.getClass().getMethod(createMethodName);
        Object classInstance = createMethod.invoke(factory);
        
        
        String methodName = "";
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            try {
                methodName = "set" + entry.getKey().toString().substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + entry.getKey().toString().substring(1);
                Method setNameMethod = classInstance.getClass().getMethod(methodName, getType(entry.getValue()));
                setNameMethod.invoke(classInstance, parseEntry(entry.getValue()));
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                LOGGER.log(null, "Attribute " + entry.getKey().toString() + " is not a valid attribute for this object. Is it spelled correctly?");
            }
            
        }
        return classInstance;
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException nm) {
        LOGGER.log(null, "Folder " + className + " does not reference to a valid object. Is it spelled correctly?");
    }
    return null;

}
```

Edit 2: Screenshots of error and debugger

Do not bother about Page and PageImpl, I used Page in my question to simplify, but the factory accepts the Interface Page and returns an instance of PageImpl. As you can see in the second screenshot, the object is an instance of PageImpl, so this seems to be correct.

[image]

[image]

Edit 3:
[image]

Edit 4:
Something that works for now:

```
String methodName = "get" + "Page";
        Method getListMethod = site.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
        List<Object> list = (List<Object>) getListMethod.invoke(site);
        list.add(page);
```

Comment: You mix up generics and reflections i'm Not very Save in generics/reflections in Java but in C# you could use reflections to make a generic add-Method-Info and call ist with the list as Parameter.

Comment: The list is already generic If it’s a List<Page>. It’s only the way you treat it.

Comment: Sorry, must have accidentially deleted my comment. I still don't quite get how to do it.

Comment: no problem, for deleting your comment. You could undelete it in the Browser.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `createInstance` returns a `Class<Page>` (the class object), but your list is a `List<Page>` (a list of instances).

You will need to create an instance and add it to the list, still using reflection:

```
list.add(classInstance.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());
```

The above is using an empty constructor for the class `Page`. If for example you wanted to use a constructor taking one string and one int, you would do it as such:

```
list.add(classInstance.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, Integer.class).newInstance("my string", 4));
```

Edit:. Since `classInstance` is an Object and not a class, you should be able to do this:

```
list.add(Class.forName("Page").cast(classInstance));
```

Comment: As far as I can see, OP has already an instance and ins only wants to cast it for adding.

Comment: yes, probably Class<Page> was wrong, but createInstance() already returns an instance of the class

Comment: @Nikolaus based on the first line he shows, OP gets back a `Class<Page>` and thinks it's enough to cast it to `Page` (apparently he didn't try to run it or would have seen that it will fail)

Comment: @pingpong if that's the case, you should fix your question cause it's misleading

Comment: @MatteoNNZ fixed it to Object

Comment: getting now this error: The method add(Page) in the type List<Page> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#7-of ?).

Comment: @pingpong then it means that your `classInstance` is not an instance of Page. You should probably add more details to your question, some piece of information is missing

Comment: @pingpong if you set a breakpoint and evaluate just the expressions `Class.forName("Page")` and then `Class.forName("Page").cast(classInstance)`, what do you get? What types are them? I suggest you take a screenshot of the debug view and add it to the question, without seeing what they actually are its hard to help further

Comment: I'm actually getting a ClassNotFoundException now. Class Page comes from a different project and is imported in my file. I can also use it there, but if I call Class.forName("Page"), i get the exception

Comment: @pingpong have you tried to qualify the name of the class with the package name? If you just say Page I don't think it can find it (I thought you were writing page just to simplify the code snippet on the question)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ thanks, this fixed the exception. I've added a screenshot of the debugger and a screenshot of the error to the question

Comment: @pingping can you also add the same screenshot you added for variable page but for Class.forName("...")?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ added

Comment: @pingpong Ok I've got it now. The problem is that your list is strongly typed (at compilation it is declared to take Page and nothing more), while the forName method returns a Class<?> which sure is PageImpl, but not at the eyes of your list which only wants explicitly declared Page. If you really can't change the List type, there's really no other option for you than explicitly cast your object to Page

Comment: I see.. thanks for your help! I've hoped to avoid the extra coding for all classes but seems to be no way around.